# What is the solution for this error in selenium web driver?

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, selenium-webdriver, runtime-environment

I'm new to selenium web driver automation.
When I try this code snippet to run, I got this error message.
I'm getting nervous bcz I did it according to the online web tutorial.
Please help me to go ahead.

Here is the code I tried.

```
package seleniumTest;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class TestWikipedia {

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

    driver.get("http://wikipedia.org");

    WebElement link;

    link = driver.findElement(By.linkText("English"));
    link.click();

    Thread.sleep(5000);

    WebElement searchBox;
    searchBox = driver.findElement(By.id("SearchInput"));
    searchBox.sendKeys("Software");
    Thread.sleep(5000);

    driver.quit();
}

}
```

Here is the error I have got in Eclipse console.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)
at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.getMainMethod(Unknown Source)
at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code. It is a Java version problem. Which version of Java do you compile/run the code with?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Unsupported major.minor version](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10382929/how-to-fix-java-lang-unsupportedclassversionerror-unsupported-major-minor-versi)

Comment: It is true. however need to read more before posting.. thank you

Answer (score 2):

this kind of error

```
Unsupported major.minor version
```

indicate a problem on the java version.
A general solution is to update the jdk1.8.

in this particular case i think that
your project is developed with jdk1.8 and you are trying to compile with jdk1.7.

for completeness here you find the numbers associated with the java versions.

```
Java 9 = 53,
Java 8 = 52,
Java 7 = 51,
Java 6 = 50,
Java 5 = 49,
Java 4 = 48,
Java 3 = 47,
Java 2 = 46,
Java 1 = 45
```

Comment: yeah, it is working now.. I've change my jdk version..Thanks a lot for the feedback.